# Magento Custom Helper not working, why?

Tags: magento, layout, module, helper

Trying to debug my Magento custom helper ( using 1.9CE btw)
*Mag* is the name of my custom module.

**/code/local/Mag/Layout/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mag_Layout>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Mag_Layout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <Mag_HomeLayout translate="label">
                    <label>Static ( Menu Left )</label>
                    <template>page/static-left.phtml</template>
                    <layout_handle>Static </layout_handle>
                </Mag_HomeLayout>
            </layouts>
        </page>
        <helpers>
            <nav>
                Mag_Nav_Helper
            </nav>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**/code/local/Mag/Nav/Data.php**

```
<?php

class Mag_Nav_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    // Navigation helper
    public function getNavigation()
    {
        echo "here"; exit;
        echo "FOUND". $url;
        exit;
    }
}
```

then in any LAYOUT I'm trying to call it:
Like so:

```
<?php

$helper = Mage::helper('nav');
$helper->getNavigation();
?>
```

**Expecting it would call my custom helper method but it does not,** what do i overlook here? thank you!

EDIT: Would there also be an easy way to call helpers from static blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely a typo/naming convention issue.
I'd make all names within a module uniform:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mag_Nav>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mag_Nav>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <mag_nav>
                <class>Mag_Nav_Helper</class>
            </mag_nav>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Usage:

```
$oHelper= Mage::helper( 'mag_nav' );
```

Don't forget to edit your app/etc/local/modules/Mag_Nav.xml